# Program type already present: android.support.v4.util.ArraySet$1

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

The project was running perfectly after changing to compile version with Android 10. I am getting below error when i try to build project after that build failure message is coming and stop build.

```
1>  Driver.Android -> E:\Projects\xamrine\Source\DriverAndroid\Driver\Driver\Driver.Android\bin\Debug\Driver.Android.dll
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1660,2): warning XA0122:
 Assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations' is using a deprecated attribute 
'[assembly: Java.Interop.DoNotPackageAttribute]'. Use a newer version of this NuGet package or notify the library author.
1>D8 : error : Program type already present: android.support.v4.util.ArraySet$1 \
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

can you tell me what mistake i am doing or how can i fix this.

Comment: Hi , from error logs  `Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations` is not supported in Android 10 . You can not use it in Andriod 10 now until the nuget package has been updated.

Comment: I have the same problem. In my case at least, Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations is not referenced in my code. Maybe it is referenced in one of my NuGets.